# wordpress get_var is returning null

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

in a plugin that I'm developing, i test the query in phpmyadmin:

```
SELECT id_var_avaluos from nt_var_avaluos WHERE nombre = 'Comparación de Mercado'
```

it returns to me the id, but when i do the same with wordpress, I print the query string that is the same, but using it into get_Var, it returns me null value but when nombre is in uppercase it returns me the id and in the database te column nombre is just like I exposed here.

I will explan it better:

I'm using PHPExcel to get some data from xls files. the cell where I'm bringing that data in one has uppercase data (COMPARACIÓN DE MERCADO), in ohter file is normal text (Comparación de Mercado).

using the simple sql query directly in the database it works but in wordpress, only the uppercase (first xls file) works but I don't know why the second one returns null. I've checked the cell format and doesn't have any special format in both files.

I'd appreciate any suggestions for this issue. thanks.

--

Edit: I've tested with the natural mysql_query & mysql_result and with surprise I noticed that I cannot get any result. so how I would get the proper result if the query only works in the natural phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DAMN IT!

finally I've found the problem. As  I was printing thequery sintax, it didn't have anyone trouble, but the real problem was in the Excel data extracted:

COMPARACIÓN DE MERCADO is for 1 char different to Comparación de  Mercado

it is completely imperceptible so the query didn't give me any problem until I printed with **var_dump** and I got the length and checked with Chrome inspector to get the real string.

visually in the browser **Comparación de__Mercado** looks like **Comparación de_Mercado** (suppose the underscore is space char) but in the inspector I could see the real problem. thanks anyway for helping to me

Answer (score 0):

you maybe will use this

```
SELECT id_var_avaluos from nt_var_avaluos WHERE nombre = UPPER('Comparación de Mercado')
```

Comment: unfortunelly it didn't work :( 

I've made test with the following sintax in phpmyadmin: 

`code` SELECT id_var_avaluos from nt_var_avaluos WHERE nombre = 'Comparación de Mercado' `code`

`code` SELECT id_var_avaluos from nt_var_avaluos WHERE nombre = 'COMPARACIÓN DE MERCADO' `code`

`code` SELECT id_var_avaluos from nt_var_avaluos WHERE nombre = 'COMPARACIóN DE MERCADO' `code`

each one returns me what I need but into wordpress is too strange I cannot get the same result